# Mouse disappears on second screen in 11.04 with Radeon hardware

Tags: multiple-monitors, mouse, xfce, fglrx, radeon

I'm running a 5 screen setup (5th screen disabled atm) over two Radeon HD cards, three on a 6770 and two on a 5450 (one disabled atm).

When I move my mouse onto the second screen on the first card (6770) it disappears.  Like a ghost mouse it does function on that screen, but it's not visible.

Here's a diagram of the setup

[image: IMG:]

and a screenshot of the Catalyst configuration.

[image]

(it shows the two smaller LCDs as CRTs for some reason).

System is (X)Ubuntu 11.04 and I'm running the proprietary fglrx driver  version 11.9, the window manager is Xfce4 (I installed the Xubuntu package to get it).

The weird thing is it does work *occasionally*... I just don't know what causes it to work and not work.

Do you have any ideas where I could start?

I confirmed it does the same thing on GNOME, GNOME (without effects) and Fluxbox. I can't test Unity because I uninstalled that.  Compositioning is on also.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that.